# Rails minitest, why is my article model invalid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I am starting to get into testing with minitest in Rails.  Currently my first test to see if my model is valid is returning false.  The error message itself is also very generic `Expected false to be truthy`.  I have tested everything else and all of those tests work fine.  Does anybody know what could be causing this?

article_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class ArticleTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

    def setup
      @article = Article.new(title:"Avengers Endgame", body:"I am inevitable")
    end

    test "article should be valid" do
      assert @article.valid?
    end


    test "title should be present" do
        @article.title = " "
        assert_not @article.valid?
    end



    test "body should not be too short" do
        @article.body = "aa"
        assert_not @article.valid?
    end
end
```

article.rb

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
    include Visible
    
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    has_rich_text :body
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that you're using a poor method for testing your validations.

`assert @article.valid?` and `assert_not @article.valid?` does not actually tell you anything at all about the object under test. When the test fails you're none the wiser about why it actually failed and if the failure is actually even connected to what you're proportedly testing. At best it serves as a sort of litmus test that your test setup is correct.

Instead of this "carpet bombing" approach test each validation on its own:

```
class ArticleTest < ActiveSupport::TestCas
  test "title should be present" do
    article = Article.new(title: '')
    article.valid?
    assert_includes build_article.errors[:title], "can’t be blank" 
  end

  test "body should not be too short" do
    article = Article.new(body: 'aa')
    article.valid?
    assert_includes article.errors[:body], "is too short" 
  end
end
```

Testing all the validations at once (creating a record with valid input) will be covered by your integration and system tests anyways.

Comment: Okay that makes sense thank you I will try that route then.

Comment: https://gorails.com/episodes/testing-rails-validations

Comment: The shoulda-matchers gem is also really nice for making validation testing a lot less tedius.

Answer (score 0):

You have `belongs_to :user`, which expects the `@article` to have a `user_id` [compulsorily](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default) to be present, before it can be saved.

If `user_id` is optional during creation, change this:

```
belongs_to :user
```

to

```
belongs_to :user, optional: true
```

Comment: I'm not sure I want to do that.  I'm using devise for authentication and I'm afraid that will break the application itself not just the tests I am trying to do.

Comment: @Jasper: well, then assign a user to that article.

Comment: @Jasper depends on your goal and intention. If your intent is that an `@article` can be valid without `user_id` then you have to create it as optional association. If not, then either you assert that `@artcile` is not valid or you assign user to the article.